# template function within variadic class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

Why won't the commented-line in `goo` compile? Instead I have to resort to defining the global function `hoo` instead of using the `Thing` member function `foo`?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... T>
struct Thing {
    template <typename U> void foo() {std::cout << this << '\n';}
};

template <typename U, typename... T>
void hoo (const Thing<T...>& thing) {std::cout << &thing << '\n';}

template <typename U, typename... T>
void goo (const Thing<T...>& thing) {
//  thing.foo<U>();  // Why won't this line compile?
    hoo<U>(thing);  // Using this instead.
}

int main() {
    Thing<int, double, char> thing;
    goo<short>(thing);
}
```

What is the change that is needed so that I can use foo() instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the line `thing.foo<U>()` the compiler doesn't have enough information to tell if `foo` is template or not. Use the `template` keyword to disambiguate this:

```
thing.template foo<U>();
```

Comment: Still does not compile (GCC 4.8.1).

Comment: @prestokeys What's the error?

Comment: no matching function for call to 'Thing<int, double, char>::foo() const'.  void Thing<T>::foo() [with U = short int; T = {int, double, char}] <near match>  no known conversion for implicit 'this' parameter from 'const Thing<int, double, char>*' to 'Thing<int, double, char>*'

Comment: @prestokeys `foo()` needs to be `const` since you're calling it on a `const` object.

Comment: Yes.  I realized it.